# I fail to understand the following dirname() function code

Tags: php, dirname

OS: Centos
PHP: 7.3

I am following a beginner's course by Kevin Skoglund about PHP. These are a few lines from the code. I understand `define()` and `dirname()` functions. I just don't understand what is happening here.

```
define("PRIVATE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
define("PROJECT_PATH", dirname(PRIVATE_PATH));
define("PUBLIC_PATH", PROJECT_PATH . '/public');
define("SHARED_PATH", PRIVATE_PATH . '/shared');
```

this is the output of the 4 constants

```
/var/www/html/globe_bank/private
/var/www/html/globe_bank
/var/www/html/globe_bank/public
/var/www/html/globe_bank/private/shared
```

I don't understand why does `dirname(__FILE__)` goes only until directory **private**. Doesn't **FILE** suppose to be go to all the to root directory.
Same is with the 2nd constant

`PROJECT_PATH`. Why do we have to pass the parameter `PRIVATE_PATH`?

Here is another section of code.

```
$public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/public') + 7;
$doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $public_end);
define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);
```

Comment: Output values and it will be clear.

Comment: just echo something like `echo PRIVATE_PATH;`, so that you know what it looks like. plus, googling like `php strpos function` helps

Comment: its not the function that I don't understand, Its what they are doing, that is making me confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the *Doesn't __FILE__ suppose to be go to all the to root directory* remark means (root directory is always `/` on Unix, you don't need a function to calculate it dynamically). Also, please note that [dirname()](https://php.net/dirname) is just a string function, it doesn't check or care about your actual disk contents.

Having no idea of what you were expecting, the definition of `dirname()` is:

> Given a string containing the path of a file or directory, this function will return the parent directory's path that is levels up from the current directory.

Since [__FILE__](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is defined as:

> The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.

The output is clear:

- For files, full path of the directory where the file is.
- For directories, the full path of the parent directory.

Beware that your course is possibly terribly outdated because `__DIR__` exists as alternative to `dirname(__FILE__)` since PHP/5.3.0:

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned.